# % OFF all items in category x & Cart Subtotal must be = or less than $

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

[image]

I am trying to add a rule to my shopping cart for the following.  Purchase $1000 or less of one or multiple items in Category 202 to receive a 10% discount.  I can only get this rule to work if I use "ANY" instead of "ALL".  The problem with this is if someone adds an item in their cart outside of Category 202, they still receive the discount on that item and that item contributes to the $ amount (which triggers the rule (valid for rule 2&3).  I want to apply the following rules:

1. Purchase items in Category 202 up to $1000 get 10%
2. Purchase items in Category 202 over $1000 and under $5000 get 20%
3. Purchase items in Category 202 over $5000 get 30%

Is anyone able to tell me why this only works with "ANY" or am I doing something wrong here?

Really appreciate your help :-)

Comment: As an update to this, I have made this first rule work by doing the following:  In the CONDITIONS TAB: If ALL of these conditions are TRUE: If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true: Category is 202 Price in cart less than 1000   ACTIONS TAB: If ALL of these conditions are TRUE: Category IS NOT ONE OF (entered all other categories).....however.  The 10% discount apply even after $1000 ?????

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on following images.

Hope this helps you.

**Expected Output**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Ashish for your help.  This will only work when I select "ANY" instead of ALL.  We need it to be both rules as you have said.  Do you feel this is a fault with our system?

Comment: which version you are using. as you can see in above images i used it for ALL condition and this is working.

Comment: I know very frustrating.  It is Magento ver. 1.9.1.1

Comment: need to come for a chat other wise this becomes very long join me @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40647/chat-with-charlie

Comment: Sorry Ashish, I don't seem to be able to type in the chat room...I think I have not been a member long enough?

Comment: In the area I need to type I see this message:-You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: ok can you please show me snap of your rule
1) Rule Information 2)Conditions 3) Actions

Comment: Yes how do I send an image in the "ADD Comment" Section

Comment: upload you images to either google drive or some other temp uploader  and send the links here

Comment: ok won't be a moment

Comment: you can use http://www.filedropper.com/

Comment: :) your problem yet to be fix say after fix

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpem4zxcdknm7qy/Shop%20Cart%20Issue.jpg?dl=0

Comment: this should work show me shpoing cart issue

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p60l27jmo1mw2m/Shopping%20Cart.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The problem is with the word "ALL".  When I change it to "ANY" it works...but I need ALL to work

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3x6wjzb8gj32t3c/Shopping%20Cart%20Any.jpg?dl=0

Comment: If I use any then any other categories are discounted.

Comment: i think it is applying GST additionally discount is not applying

Comment: add new sample product in 202 category and try over that and let me know if it works or not

Comment: The GST is a usual function for us....I will try a new product and advise.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes the new product is working...what does that mean do you think?

Comment: have you checked all condition on new product is it working properly ? The problem which you face are not appearing in new one ?

Comment: This means their is no issue with rule need to check on  product level check once that product which you used previously are assigned to multiple category or not and if yes then did you added a right category product in a cart.

Comment: Thanks Ashish..I will check that and let you know. Can't thank you enough for your time.

Comment: :) if you are satisfied with the answer then you can accept and up vote it  so that other can get help from this.

Comment: Yes it is working well, thanks so much again..I will vote  now...thanks Ashish

Comment: grt what was the problem.

Comment: One more question....would you be able to tell me how I can vote?...thanks again for the resolution.

Comment: on top left side of answer you will find a 0 with upper and lower sign click on upper arrow to +ve vote and down arrow for -ve vote  and below down arrow their is right sign to accept the answer for which you might required more reputation but you can upvote it.

Comment: have you don't got it ?